# How to write into the database those records which choose in the checkboxlist?

Tags: asp.net, database, checkboxlist

I have a little problem regarding my asp.net project.I have register.aspx,login.aspx and default.aspx pages inside of my asp.net project.

By the way,entering those informations which wanted from those users into the textboxes inside of the register.aspx page and after clicked the button,
    the information is writing into the database.In sum,my project is that.
    My question is;I will give multiple-choice with checkboxlist and I will write to the table inside of the database those items which choose in the checkboxlist.

In sum,How to write into the database those records in the checkboxlist?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `iterate CheckBoxList`

```
  String selectedItem = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            string.Format(selectedItem, ",", item.Text);
        }
    }

    if (selectedItem != string.Empty)
    {
        selectedItem = selectedItem.Substring(1);
    }

    //selectedItem Will give you Id's of Selected checkbox 3,4,7
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar-First of all,thanks for your interesting.But,I want to write by putting a comma between of each item to table inside of the database.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar- I don't want to record  ID's of  selected checkbox.I just want to record text near of selected checkbox.

Comment: I tried code.However,I have a problem regarding code.When I run code,I am getting "startIndex cannot be larger than lenght of string.parameter name:startIndex" error.

Comment: I tried.I'm not getting the error.But, it's coming as NULL the field(I'm using a column called hobby)inside of table.And it was record the same record twice.